# Avoid pushing some files to public Repository

Tags: git

I have seen this question
[Can I add a file to my local Git repo but not push it to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629211/can-i-add-a-file-to-my-local-git-repo-but-not-push-it-to-remote), but I have a different scenario.

I have a public remote Repo in Github (but could be anything supporting Git, from Google Code to Visual Studio Online). I have some files that I do not want to share with the public, but I want to have them in my local Repository. Think of Certificates, Private keys, deploy configuration files, *et similia*. Shortly, it is not about the size, but about *secrets* and  *privacy*.

Ideally, I would have a **transform** command in Git that, using a configuration file with rules a-la .gitignore, init/push/pull to/from a transformed repository.

```
+----------+             +--------+
| internal |             | public |
+----------+             +--------+
      ^                       ^
      |                       |
 +--------+            +-------------+
 |  local |  ==(*)==>  | transformed |
 +--------+            +-------------+
```

The techniques that one may use, with current Git version and I am aware of, are:

1. ignore the files or move them out of the local Repo
2. confine such files in a sub-tree or module, which is not published
3. server hooks to skip these files

Options 1 and 3 are similar and I end up not versioning the files. The second is awkward and imposes an artificial structure on my directories and files, often hard to setup.

Comment: This is option 2, which means moving files to unnatural places.

Comment: Take a look at `git update-index --skip-worktree`. The files you flag with `skip-worktree` will be considered unchanged by git no matter what. This means you can change them locally with sensitive data and then ignore these changes.

Comment: This is also interesting, but must check the behavior of other tools like SourceTree or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **git-filter-branch**, it may be something that interests you.

It does create an extra commit though.

And you need to be very wary about the history being rewritten.

Ref: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch

Another approach might be to create a "push" branch, and when you rebase the push branch from your development branch, just remove the files that you don't want exposed (using a script or something similar).

Personally, I think using a different branch for pushing would be easier to maintain.

Comment: This is interesting, need to explore

Comment: filter-branch can produce what I am looking for but it is too expensive for the workflow I have in mind.
This discussion gave me some ideas, that I will post for discussion.