# Files stored in Git but not pushed to remote

Tags: git

I have some scripts and scratch files which is useful to me and I would like to keep it in git, but they are not required for the production environment, nor useful for anyone else on the team.

I there a way to tell git specifically not to push this folder to a remote, but still track changes locally?

I'm not even sure if this is the best option for this. So let me know if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Short answer: I don't think there's a practical solution for you.  These links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21629451/421195 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12019595/421195

Comment: You could put them in a subdirectory and make that a separate git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Git takes snapshots of the entire repository tree, so there's no way to push only part of the tree, since doing so would change the structure of the data pushed.

However, there are options.  First, you could just put them in a separate directory outside of the other repository, and just make it a repository that you keep track of independently.  You can also make a separate repository that's a subdirectory and add that subdirectory to `.git/info/exclude` (which is like `.gitignore` but not checked in) in the main repository so you don't accidentally add it.

If you're storing the repository outside of the tree but you need the scripts to be in the tree, you can symlink them and exclude the symlinks in the same way as I mentioned above.

If doing this is difficult in your project, you may wish to suggest to your team that they invest a small amount of time to make it easier.  If you have such scripts, many other people probably do as well, in my experience.  After all, the worst they could say is "no."